# какой тип имеет error в typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Линтер ругается на конструкцию ... catch (error) {... , говорит Object is of type 'unknown'. (Объект имеет тип «неизвестно». ) пробовал ставить тип unknown но не знаю как сделать проверку что этот объект имеет тип Error. Подскажите плиз)

Comment: никак. в typescript в блоке catch может быть либо `unknown` либо `any`, другой тип подставить невозможно. Однако можно привести его к нужному типу внутри блока catch

Comment: @Grundy можешь показать пример? спасибо огромное за инфу

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#unknown-on-catch-clause-bindings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начиная с [Typescript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables) в `catch` для переменной по умолчанию используется тип `unknown`. До этого по умолчанию использовался тип `any`. Так как в js в значение этой переменной может быть что угодно и нельзя никак угадать что именно будет, в typescript ограничили возможность указания типов только `any` и `unknown`.

Таким образом для решения нужно либо явно его указать:

```
catch(error: any) {
```

и работать как обычно, либо добавить проверку внутри самого `catch`, например

```
catch(error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        // можно работать с error как Error
    }
}
```

либо, если ты точно знаешь какие ошибки могут быть, воспользоваться приведением

```
const err = error as Error;
```

Comment: благодарю, очень ценная, полная и оперативная информация)